How do I insert SharePoint metadata into PowerPoint presentation?
I use custom metadata in several libraries for Word documents.  Using QuickParts and then Document Properties I can insert those metadata tags directly into the document.
Now, some of our documents utilizing screenshots and lots of images would be much better in PowerPoint.  I can't seem to get them to connect though.  I have found VBA scripts to pull data from the PPT document properties, but the SharePoint metadata fields do not seem to be available.
Does anyone know how to do this?
